# self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) returning wrong cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, uistoryboard

I have a UITableView (multiple sections) with custom dynamic cells. Each cell has a UIStepper representing selected quantity.

In order to send the selected quantity (UIStepper.value) from the cell back to my `UITableViewController`, I have implemented the following protocol:

```
protocol UITableViewCellUpdateDelegate {
    func cellDidChangeValue(cell: MenuItemTableViewCell)
}
```

And this is the IBAction in my custom cell where the UIStepper is hooked:

```
@IBAction func PressStepper(sender: UIStepper) {

    quantity = Int(cellQuantityStepper.value)

    cellQuantity.text = "\(quantity)"

    self.delegate?.cellDidChangeValue(self)
}
```

And from within my `UITableViewController` I capture it via:

```
func cellDidChangeValue(cell: MenuItemTableViewCell) {

    guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) else {
        return
    }

    // Update data source - we have cell and its indexPath
    let itemsPerSection = items.filter({ $0.category == self.categories[indexPath.section] })
    let item = itemsPerSection[indexPath.row]

    // get quantity from cell
    item.quantity = cell.quantity        
}
```

The above setup works well, for most cases. I can't figure out how to solve the following problem. Here's an example to illustrate:

1. I set a `UIStepper.value` of 3 for cell 1 - section 1.
2. I scroll down to the bottom of the table view so that cell 1 - section 1 is well out of view.
3. I set a `UIStepper.value` of 5 for cell 1 - section 4.
4. I scroll back up to the top of so that cell 1 - section 1 is back into view.
5. I increase UIStepper by 1. So quantity should have been 4. Instead, it's 6.

Debugging the whole thing shows that this line (in the delegate implementation of `UITableViewController`) gets the wrong quantity. It seems `indexPathForCell` is getting a wrong cell thus returning a wrong quantity?

```
// cell.quantity is wrong
item.quantity = cell.quantity
```

For completeness sake, here's cellForRowAtIndexPath implementation where the cells are being dequeued as they come into view:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "MenuItemTableViewCell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuItemTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self

    // Match category (section) with items from data source
    let itemsPerSection = items.filter({ $0.category == self.categories[indexPath.section] })
    let item = itemsPerSection[indexPath.row]

    // cell data
    cell.cellTitle.text = item.name + "  " + formatter.stringFromNumber(item.price)!
    cell.cellDescription.text = item.description
    cell.cellPrice.text = String(item.price)

    if item.setZeroQuantity == true {
        item.quantity = 0
        cell.cellQuantityStepper.value = 0
        cell.cellQuantity.text = String(item.quantity)

        // reset for next time
        item.setZeroQuantity = false
    }
    else {
        cell.cellQuantity.text = String(item.quantity)
    }
    .....
    ....
    ..
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the stepper value in the `else` clause in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
else {
    cell.cellQuantity.text = String(item.quantity)
    cell.cellQuantityStepper.value = Double(item.quantity)
}
```

Otherwise the stepper retains the value from the previous time the cell was used.